# $\frac{1}{a_n}\int_0^{a_n} f(x) \,dx \rightarrow f(0)$ if $a_n\rightarrow 0$

Tags: calculus, analysis

The full question I'm looking at:

Suppose that $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Suppose $a_n>0$ satisfy $a_n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Prove that $\frac{1}{a_n}\int_0^{a_n} f(x) \,dx \rightarrow f(0)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

**My attempt so far:**

Since $a_n\rightarrow 0$, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N\implies 0<a_n<1$. So $f$ is continuous on $[0,a_n]$.

From this, we see that since $f$ is continuous and hence sequentially continous on $[0,a_n]$, $f(a_n)\rightarrow f(0)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Using FTC, define $F(x):=\int_0^x f(t) \,dt$.

Then for any $n>N$, $\frac{1}{a_n}\int_0^{a_n} f(x) \,dx=\frac{F'(a_n)}{a_n}$.

I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(a_n) \rightarrow f(0)$ for any sequence tending to $0$, also $$M_n= \max\{f(x)| 0<x<a_n\}\rightarrow f(0)$$

Similarly for $m_n$, the minimum.
Then
$$m_n\int_0^{a_n} dx = m_n a_n \le \int_0^{a_n} f(x) dx\le M_n\int_0^{a_n} dx = M_n a_n$$
Now divide by $a_n$ and let $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Ah clever. Question confused me as it was sandwiched between questions concerning the FTC, so I thought it would also want me to use the FTC.

Comment: @Maylor There is often more than one solution to such questions. It depends mostly on your intuition which one is the one you understand best or which comes to your mind first.

Comment: I interpret this question to be about proving the FTC for endpoints; it's equivalent to $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t) dt$ being right-differentiable at $0$ with $F'(0^+) = f(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps use Mean-Value Theorem.
$$
\exists c \in (0,a_n):
F(a_n) - F(0) = a_n f(c).
$$
Since $a_n\to 0$
$$
\lim_{a_n\to 0}\frac{1}{a_n}(F(a_n - F(0)) = f(0)
$$
using the continuity of $f$ and the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly by mean value theorem we have $$\frac{1}{a_{n}}\cdot\int_{0}^{a_{n}}f(x)\,dx = \frac{1}{a_{n}}\cdot(a_{n} - 0)f(c) = f(c)$$ for some $c \in (0, a_{n})$. When $a_{n} \to 0$ then $c \to 0$ and $f(c) \to f(0)$.